# Google Places API (Adding API Key) Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-places-api

I installed the google places gem on Rails. When I try to set up the `@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(API_KEY)` I get several errors.

I entered my API key and replaced `client` with `restaurant`. I tried running this in the folder and I get a syntax error.

When I tried to run the same thing in console, I get the following error:

> NameError (uninitialized constant here)

Can anyone let me know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the API key like if it was defined somehow, but it's not. That should be a string

```
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new("your api key") # between quotes
```

or using a variable

```
api_key = "your api key"
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(api_key)
```